# enthought python distribution wx

Tags: python, 64-bit, pygame, wxwidgets, enthought

For some reason my 64 bit EPD can't import wx.
I also tried to install the wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-py2.7 version from the wx site.
It installed successfully, but is no where to be found on my harddrive.
I checked the sitepackes for 2.7 and the EPD 7.2.2. where all the modules usually should be installed. 
I am confused. 
This raises a similar question. 
How can I install modules that are not part of EPD ?
I also didn't have luck to install other modules.
And every time I try to import older modules it doesn't work as well.

Often I get error message that architectures in universal rapper is wrong.
For example pygame doesn’t have a 64 bit version that works with 2.7, so I installed the 32 bit version.
If I try to do the trick arch -i386 /Path to python , I get "Bad CPU type in executable".
I am running a 64bit version of Python on a 64 bit Mac OS.

I wonder if the Enthougt 7.2 is equivalent with the 2.7 Python.
And if not, what I assume, what the differences are.

Any hints who can solve this, would be awesome.

Thanks for your patients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. The only way around it that has worked for me is to uninstall your EPD version (`$ sudo remove-EPD-7.2-1`, or whichever version you have) and reinstall the 32 bit version. Wx comes as part of the EPD package, so once you have downloaded the 32 bit version there is no need to download and install wx.